# Time Machine + PC backup to single external hard drive

Tags: backup, time-machine, external-disk, ntfs

Does "backing up" read/write data to a hard drive?

I'd like to backup both my Mac (using Time Machine) & my PC to a single 3 TB Seagate external hard drive using the USB port on my wireless router.

If this is relevant, the router supports the following file system types for full read/write access:
• FAT16   • FAT32   • NTFS   • NTFS with compression format enabled  • Ext2  • Ext3   • Ext4

The router supports the following file system types with read-only access:
• HFS
• HFS+

Seagate provides software (Paragon) to enable a Macbook to read & write in NTFS, but also says that installing the software prevents backing up with Time Machine. If you are familiar with Paragon, do they provide an alternative backup method to Time Machine?

Comment: Paragon make a fully paid NTFS solution [Paragon NTFS](https://www.paragon-software.com/ufsdhome/ntfs-mac/) $20 which has been running alongside my [local not networked] Time Machine for years - however I have no knowledge as regards the rest of the setup, sorry.

Comment: Could you not just partition the 3TB drive into an HFS+ partition for the Mac backup, and an NTFS partition for the Windows backup? Means you have to set an upper limit on the amount of backup space used by each, but seems like it would be the easiest solution.

Comment: @calum_b "The router supports the following file system types with read-only access: • HFS • HFS+"

Comment: Usually when a wireless router is involved, the file system is less important than the actual protocol you'll access the drive with. In particular, software such as Paragon cannot be used at all. Usually wireless routers that enable sharing of a disk do so over SMB, AFP, NFS or similar. You'll want to detail which specific wireless router you have.

Comment: What about just connecting the drive to your Mac/PC and sharing it over the network using SMB?